# MailComposer Subject from Text Field

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Inside my MailComposeViewController I have this line of code to tell the view what the subject needs to be:

```
[mailer setSubject: _mailSubject];
```

_MailSubject is the UITextField name and of course setSubject is telling the UITextField to be the subject. My problem is that every time I enter in the subject into the UITextField and press my compose button, the app crashes. I know that it isn't the MailComposerViewController because I can enter in my email body into a UITextField and not have it crash. Here is the warning that appears next to it:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'UITextField'*_strong to parameter of type 'NSString*'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are most likely getting a compiler warning. Don't ignore compiler warnings. Doing so typically leads to crashes at runtime.

Comment: You failed to appreciate that you can't just send an arbitrary object as a parameter -- it's got to be the right type.  You're sending a UITextField to a method that expects an NSString.  It's not too terrible that you didn't recognize this from the start, but when you got the error you should have consulted MailComposeViewController spec, recognized that you needed an NSString, then consulted the UITextField spec to figure out how to get that NSString.  You shouldn't have to ask for help here for such a simple problem.

Comment: I see that now. I am not very good at Cocoa and am learning it from experimentation and documentations. I forgot to add that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the text from the text field:

```
[mailer setSubject:_mailSubject.text];
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have seen that but like I commented above, I am a newbie and forgot to add the .text to the end. Thanks for your help!